# java - Random inside while loop causes infinite loop with all same numbers

Tags: java, random, while-loop

On the Programming By Doing website I'm stuck on the DoubleDice exercise.  It's supposed to run a while loop until you come up with the same value for each dice (doubles - 3 and 3, 4 and 4, etc.)

I've input what I think to be the correct code, but I get this infinite loop that prints out the exact same "randoms" every time through the while loop.

I've pondered this for about a day and decided to give it to SO.

Thanks.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class diceDoubles {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Random dice = new Random();

        int roll1 = 1 + dice.nextInt(6);
        int roll2 = 1 + dice.nextInt(6);

        System.out.println("HERE COMES THE DICE!\n");

        while(roll1 != roll2) {

            System.out.println("Die 1: " + roll1);
            System.out.println("Die 2: " + roll2);
            System.out.println("The total is " + (roll1 + roll2) + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So why do you think your values should change? Which part of your code makes you think so?

Comment: You never update `roll1` and `roll2` in the loop so the condition never changes.

Comment: Values are supposed to change until it generates doubles...

Comment: You never update roll1 and roll2 so they create an infinite loop, easy as that

Comment: I had a feeling that I need to "reinitialize" the variables.  (new to Java.  sure that reinitialize word is wrong)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add "variables `roll1` and `roll12` update code" to `while` loop, like this:

```
while(roll1 != roll2) {

    roll1 = 1 + dice.nextInt(6);
    roll2 = 1 + dice.nextInt(6);

    System.out.println("Die 1: " + roll1);
    System.out.println("Die 2: " + roll2);
    System.out.println("The total is " + (roll1 + roll2) + "\n");
}
```

Comment: You're completely right, that went right over my head

Comment: Thanks.  Initially I copied and pasted my int roll1... int roll2 code to the while loop and it didn't fix it.  

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Spend some time familiarizing yourself with the control flow of the code, and what each statement does.

```
<type> <identifier>;
```

Lines like this DECLARE a variable - i.e., give it a type, and a place in the namespace. Once a variable is declared, references to it will be consistent within its scope, and it cannot be re-assigned. (Mostly. There's some trickiness with member variable and local variables sharing a name, but you don't need to worry about that.)

Note that this doesn't assign a value. Primitive data types (int, boolean, double, etc), will have a default value (`0` or `false`), which references will default to `null`.

```
<identifier> = <expression>;
```

computes the value of an expression, and updates an identifier to hold that value. You can combine these into:

```
<type> <identifier> = <expression>;
```

Which will declare a variable and immediately assign it a value.

```
while(<condition>) { <expressions> }
```

executes the expressions again and again until the condition becomes false. It *only* repeats the expressions between the curly braces, though.
In your code, nothing between those braces (i.e., "in the body of the while loop") actually updates those values. You only call the assignment statement outside of the while loop, so nothing ever changes.

Comment: I will.  Thanks for the terminology.  And the tips.